# How to indicate if narrow-to-region is currently in effect

Tags: advice, fringe, narrowing

I have advised the narrow and widen functions so that the fringe color indicates if narrowing is active:

```
(advice-add 'narrow-to-region :after
            '(lambda (&rest args)
               (set-face-attribute 'fringe
                nil :background my-fringe-narrow-bg)))

(advice-add 'widen :after
            '(lambda (&rest args)
               (set-face-attribute 'fringe
                nil :background (face-attribute 'default :background))))
```

This works very well. However, sometimes the fringe gets colored by my advice while I did not call any narrowing function. One example is `'org-table-sort-lines`: it calls `'narrow-to-region` within a `'save-restriction` block but does not call `'widen` afterwards, of course.

So, how can I find out if `'narrow-to-region` have been called from within `'save-restriction`?

**EDIT**: Something like this would help as well:

```
(advice-add 'save-restriction :before
            '(lambda (&rest args)
               (ad-deactivate 'narrow-to-region)))    

(advice-add 'save-restriction :after
            '(lambda (&rest args)
               (ad-activate 'narrow-to-region)))
```

However this doesn't work, I get the error: `advice--normalize: Advice impossible: save-restriction is a special form`.

Comment: You might be able check the stack with `backtrace` or something, but I would suggest just checking the narrowing status in a `post-command-hook` instead.

Comment: Well, but how do I find this out? And what if the buffer was already narrowed in the first place (since `'save-restriction` restores narrowing's already in place)? I don't think this helps.

Comment: Just to make sure: you do know that whether the buffer is already indicated in the (default) mode-line, right? I guess you prefer showing it in the fringe, but just thought I'd mention this.

Comment: Please consider retitling the question. The accepted answer does not really say how to tell whether `narrow-to-region` was called within `save-restriction`. But it does answer what is apparently your real question.

Comment: Drew: yes I know about the indicator in the mode-line but I tend to overlook it. Also, I modified the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with npostavs' suggestion. Something like:

```el
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-narrowed-fringe-status)

(defun my-narrowed-fringe-status ()
  "Make the fringe background reflect the buffer's narrowing status."
  (set-face-attribute
   'fringe nil :background (if (buffer-narrowed-p)
                               my-fringe-narrow-bg
                             nil)))
```

Comment: Hm, thanks a lot, it works! I wonder, though, that `'describe-variable` doesn't show `buffer-narrowed-p`.

Comment: That's because it's a function. Hence `(buffer-narrowed-p)` rather than `buffer-narrowed-p`.